# Using DELETE FROM...RETURNING in a PostgreSQL IF / THEN Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, if-statement, sql-delete

I have this code:

```
DO $$
returns table (msg varchar(500), isSuccessful BIT) as $BODY$
declare
newID integer := null;
id integer := 100;
BEGIN
IF newID is NULL 
then delete from table1 t1 where t1.id = id;
delete from table2 t2 where t2.id = id
returning 'test' as msg, 1 as isSuccessful;
else insert into table1(id, name)
values(id, 'testname');
END IF;
END $$;
```

When I run this, I'm getting this error:

*ERROR: syntax error at or near "returns"*

I originally didn't have the `returns table`  line, but after some research it's my understanding that I need to establish a table for the data in the `returning` line to write into.

What I want to return is the following:

| msg | isSuccessful |
| --- | --- |
| test | 1 |

What am I doing wrong with my `returns table` line and how do I achieve the output I'm looking for? Also, do I have to create a function in order for this to work?

Comment: Your function is expection an array as result. what happens IF newID is **not** NULL . You arent returning anything !

Comment: @Hamza Ok updated my code to insert into table1 for the ELSE. Still getting the same error for my RETURNS TABLE line.

Comment: You can't `return` anything from a `DO`(anonymous) function. See [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver My understanding of functions is limited, but I understand your comment. Is there a way to achieve my desired output without defining a function at all?

Comment: Depends what you want to do with info. If you just want a message the `RAISE NOTICE 'msg: %,  isSuccessful: %', msg, isSuccessful;`. See here [Raising messages/errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE).  Otherwise  you will have to write it out to a table. FYI, Postgres has [boolean](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) so I would use that rather then `BIT`. I would spend some time here [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Gotcha, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example how you can insert deleted records from table `sample1` into table `sample2`:

```
with deleted_rows as (
    delete from test.sample1 where id = 123712
    returning id, first_name 
)
insert into test.sample2 (id, first_name) 
SELECT id, first_name from deleted_rows;
```

But, if you want to get table on this format (msg, isSuccessful) then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.delete_data(p_id integer)
RETURNS table (msg text, isSuccessful boolean)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare 
    deleted_id integer; 
begin

    delete from test.sample1 where id = p_id
    returning id into deleted_id;
    -- if this query does not delete any record, so variable "deleted_id" will be null

    if (deleted_id is not null) then 
        return query 
        select 'Success Deleted', true;
    else 
        return query 
        select 'No records deleted', false;
    end if;

end;
$function$
;
```